# MongoDB: Aggregating and counting items per user_id

Tags: mongodb, count, mapreduce

I am quite new to MongoDB and Map-Reduce and I am having trouble finding the solution to my problem.

I have multiple documents stored with an "user_id" and an array of different items. The user_id is not unique. I want a collection where i can see how many times a user used a certain item.

The documents look like this:

```
db.items.find()
{"items": ["abc", "def", ghi], "user_id": 328252955}
{"items": ["klm"], "user_id": 328250000}
{"items": ["abc", ghi], "user_id": 328252955}
```

And i want something like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "user_id" : 328252955}, 
        "value" : [{"items": "abc", "count" : 2},{"items": "ghi", "count" : 2},{"items": "def", "count" : 1}]
}

{ "_id" : { "user_id" : 328250000}, 
        "value" : [{"items": "klm", "count" : 1}]
}
```

But the best solution i could muster wasn't anything like that, because the documents had another structure if a user used more than one kind of item.

It looked like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "user_id" : 328252955 }, 
        "value" : { 
            "preferences" : [[{"items": "abc", "count" : 2},{"items": "ghi", "count" : 2},{"items": "def", "count" : 1}]]
              }
}

{ "_id" : { "user_id" : 328250000}, 
        "value" : {"items": "klm", "count" : 1}
}
```

def

To do that i mapped user_id and items to one key and emitted "count: 1" as value. 
The resulting document looked like this:

```
db.items_01.find()
{ "_id" : { "user_id" : 328250000, "items" : [  "klm" ] }, "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : { "user_id" : 328252955, "items" : [  "abc" ] }, "value" : { "count" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : { "user_id" : 328252955, "items" : [  "ghi" ] }, "value" : { "count" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : { "user_id" : 328252955, "items" : [  "def" ] }, "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
```

Map-Reduce for that:

```
map = function() {

  if (this.items == null){
    return;
  }

  for(var i in this.items){
    key = { user_id: this.user_id, items: this.items[i] };    
    value = { count: 1 };
    emit(key, value);
  }
}

function reduce(key, values) {
    var cnt = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        cnt += 1;
    }
    return { count: cnt };
}
db.items.mapReduce(map, reduce, "items_01")
```

To get my final output shown above i used another Map-Reduce function, where i used user_id as key and "items" and "count" as value.

Map-Reduce for that:

```
map = function() {
    key = { user_id: this._id.user_id };    
    value = {items: this._id.items, count: this.value.count};
    emit(key, value);  
}



reduce = function(key, values) {
  return {preferences:[values]};
}
db.items_01.mapReduce(map, reduce, "items_01_01")
```

I know that i cannot return the values array. But what else can i do?

Thank you for your help. It will be much appreciated. I have already spent days on this  and i am still trying to figure out the best solution.

Comment: Did you try using aggregation using unwind and then grouping on the item and user? The results will be flattened, but you could combine them on the client.

Comment: I tried the following two, but only got empty results back. `db.usertags_count_01_01.aggregate({$project: {user_id: 1, items: 1, count: 1, preferences: 1}},{$unwind:"$preferences" })` and `db.usertags_count_01_01.aggregate({$project: {user_id: 1, items: 1, count: 1}},{$unwind:"$preferences" })`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like:

```
db.items.aggregate(
     {$project: { items: 1, user_id: 1}}, 
     {$unwind: "$items"}, 
     { $group: 
         { _id: { user_id: "$user_id", item: "$items" }, 
           count: { $sum: 1 }  
         }  
     })
```

#### Explanation

This selects/narrows the fields that will be used in the aggregation:

```
 {$project: { items: 1, user_id: 1}}
```

This unwinds the `items` array. That means that for every item in the `items` array, the pipeline will have a distinct document with the fields that were projected in the first step:

```
 {$unwind: "$items"},
```

Results:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52dbed562c3f37cf53664faf"),
    "items" : "abc",
    "user_id" : 328252955
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52dbed562c3f37cf53664faf"),
    "items" : "def",
    "user_id" : 328252955
},  // ETC...
```

Then, finally the `$group` which groups on the `user_id` and the `item` (which I've renamed to just be item using the syntax `item: "$items"`). For each distinct grouped value, `1` is added to a new field called `count` by using `$sum` of `1`.

```
{ $group: 
         { _id: { user_id: "$user_id", item: "$items" }, 
           count: { $sum: 1 }  
         }  
}
```

#### Final Results

Using your sample data, would result in something like:

```
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "user_id" : 328250000,
                            "item" : "klm"
                    },
                    "count" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "user_id" : 328252955,
                            "item" : "ghi"
                    },
                    "count" : 2
            },
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "user_id" : 328252955,
                            "item" : "def"
                    },
                    "count" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "user_id" : 328252955,
                            "item" : "abc"
                    },
                    "count" : 2
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: I might have overseen something, but isn't the result basically the same as the fourth box of code, except for me having the additional "value"? Isn't it possible to get something like the second box of code?

Also i added collection names to my first post to make it more clear.

But thank you for your detailed explanation of the $unwind operator, i think i understand now how it works.

Comment: With aggregation, I don't know that it's possible to do efficiently (if at all). The unique combination is a user and an item. So, that's what's returned in the pipeline.

Comment: It is trivial, actually, just add another $group stage.